# Nivo Slider no carga las imagenes

Tags: javascript

¿Porque mi pagina no carga las imagenes?

Estoy haciendo un `slider` con el `plugin` `Nivo` `Slider`, y de repente me marco un error en mi código de `javascript`, ya lo modifique de varias maneras, pero sigo con el mismo error, me dice que no es una función, y pues no entiendo del todo a que se refiere eso, a continuación pongo una `imagen` con el error que me manda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que te hace falta incluir la librería jquery antes de la nivoSlider.

Comment: si lo tengo asi

Comment: Podrias revisar que tu ruta donde cargas la libreria nivoSlider sea correcta porque puede que no se este cargando, revisa en la pestaña sources de las herramientas del navegador si se esta cargando.

Comment: las rutas si estan bien, ya he checado y se puede accesar a las librerias desde el navegador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes de incluir aparte de la `librería` `nivoSlider` la de `jQuery`, algo como esto, el problema que tienes es por que no estas referenciando bien la `librería` o te hace falta la de `jQuery`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nivoslider/3.2/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load', function(){
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
    </script>
<body >
     <div id="slider">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: de hecho lo tengo con el jquery 3.3.1, pero el error dice que ".nivoSlider" no es una funcion, es decir que no es problema de la libreria, ademas en donde pusiste la etiqueta de "id="slider"" tengo una clase que es : class="nivoSlider"

Comment: @Macx si encuentro una solución entonces modifico mi respuesta, y si tu la encuentras edita tu pregunta con la respuesta, muchas gracias.

Comment: si, ya la encontre, me marcaba el error porque tenia 2 librerias de jquery, solo por eso

Comment: @Macx que bien amigo, si ves que el error era en la librería, suerte!

Comment: @Macx si crees que esta respuesta fue suficiente para tu pregunta, marca como correcta.